# Artifactory Cocoapods include/white list

Tags: ios, cocoapods, artifactory

In our company we are establishing Artifactory into our toolchain. We have now a remote repository for the CocoaPods repository. As we are required to control the pods that are used, we would like to white list allowed pods with the include function.

[image: Include patterns]

So if we use a repository without restriction, everything works fine. But if we have an include pattern for a library, e.g. see print screen, then we get an error on the fetchIndex request of Artifactory. In the logs, this is what it looks like:

`20161216094625|3|REQUEST|someIP|username|GET|/api/pods/cocoapods-master/index/fetchIndex|HTTP/1.1|404|0`

Does anybody have made experiences with white listing pods through artifactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory caches the index under the `.specs` folder in your cocoapods repository whether it is a local repo or a remote one (it will be in the `cache` repo if remote).

The index is cached mostly for performance reasons, and is required for the normal flow of the `cocoapods repo-art` plugin, and any other remote repositories that point to it.

Simply add an include pattern for the `.specs` folder as well and it should work for you.

Comment: Thank you, this works mostly perfectly, but there's another issue that kind of is related to my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168255/artifactory-cocoapods-caching/41218154#41218154): How can I make sure that clients are not getting non-whitelisted pods that are not going to the cache e.g. GoogleMaps?

Comment: You can either choose what you want to be available in a separate local repository (similar to what I suggested before) - clients cannot initiate downloads from remote resources via local repos, or you can use the include/exclude patterns like you suggested but it seems kind of an ovekill to me..

Comment: BTW, You can control specific user access to repos - see [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories#CocoaPodsRepositories-WorkingwithArtifactorywithoutAnonymousAccess)